# How to nest data-bind Text

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Really simple request, I want to print Product() in an `<h4>` and Price() in a `<small>` that exists **within** the `<h4>`

```
<h4 data-bind="text:Product">
    <small data-bind="text:Price"></small>
</h4>
```

results ignore `<small>` completely

```
<h4 data-bind="html:Product() + '<small>' + Price() + '</small>'"></h4>
```

works, but seems like there should be a better way

https://jsfiddle.net/64wfpgn8/2/

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text` binding replaces all contents of the bound tag, so the small is effectively overwritten. You can get the effect you want with a virtual ko tag, though:

```
<h4><!-- ko text:Product --><!-- /ko --><small data-bind="text:Price"></small></h4>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/64wfpgn8/3/